# Trying to use Typescript conditional types to narrow down possible combinations of values that can be expected

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I'm trying to tell TypeScript that the type in the value in the 1st function parameter determines the type that the second one can have. Basically, I want to narrow down the possible combinations of types.

In the particular example, I want the 2nd parameter to be `null` if the 1sr parameter is a primitive type, and I want it to be a `Set` (of objects) if the 1st one is an object.

*The background story for those who want to know why I want to do this: This is an optimization for a recursive `stringify` function's circle detection. Cloning the `seenObjects` Set for different branches, to allow duplicates across branches that don't actually form a circle, is only necessary when the object is an object.*

**It all works well for the function from the outside**, i.e. code calling the function. In the example below, the four calls to `stringify` work exactly as desired.

**However, *inside the function* the conditional type seems to have no effect.** TS complains about the 2nd parameter possibly being `null` despite a check of the 1st parameter, and that check coupled with the conditional type - if it was used there - limits the type of the 2nd parameter to the `Set`, without `null`.

### Code

[**TS PlayGround Link** (you must enable strictNullChecks)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20isObject%20%28thing%3A%20unknown%29%3A%20thing%20is%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20typeof%20thing%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27object%27%20%26%26%20thing%20!%3D%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20stringify%3CT%20extends%20unknown%3E%28%0D%0A%20%20%20%20obj%3A%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20seenObjects%3A%20T%20extends%20Record%3Cstring%2C%20any%3E%20%3F%20Set%3CRecord%3Cstring%2C%20any%3E%3E%20%3A%20null%0D%0A%29%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28isObject%28obj%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20seenObjects.add%28obj%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%27The%20End%27%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20No%20errors%20%28good%29%0D%0Astringify%2842%2C%20null%29%3B%0D%0Astringify%28%5B%5D%2C%20new%20Set%28%29%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20ERRORS%20%28good%29%0D%0Astringify%28%5B%5D%2C%20null%29%3B%0D%0Astringify%2842%2C%20new%20Set%28%29%29%3B%0D%0A)

```js
function isObject (thing: unknown): thing is Record<string, any> {
    return typeof thing === 'object' && thing !== null;
}

function stringify<T extends unknown>(
    obj: T,
    seenObjects: T extends Record<string, any> ? Set<Record<string, any>> : null
): string {
    if (isObject(obj)) {
        seenObjects.add(obj);  // ERROR (bad)
    }

    return 'The End';
}

// No errors (good)
stringify(42, null);
stringify([], new Set());

// ERRORS (good)
stringify([], null);
stringify(42, new Set());
```

### Question

I could just add additional type refinement checks and be done with it.

However, I'm curious if anyone knows a way to achieve the desired outcome without adding code. In my actual code the value of the 2nd parameter is hard-coded dependent on the 1st one, so it seems fitting to me to solve this via static type analysis, not via additional code completely needlessly run during runtime.

*PS: Interestingly, since I'm just switching this code base over from Flow to TypeScript, in Flow I could "hack" Flow by giving it commented code, such as type refinement checks within `/*: …. */` which Flow would interpret as "live" code. So I could quiet Flow by giving it the code that it wants to see for a type check without actually putting it into the runtime, because it's in a comment.*

### Update: TS bug?

When I change the `if` condition from checking `obj` to `if (seenObjects !== null)` the error on `seenObjects` ("could be null") still remains! Despite that code now being behind an explicit check for `null`?

Comment: About the "Update" at the end: Not sure if that can be called a bug, maybe more a missing feature. You have to assign the array to a `const`, then add `as const` at the end. This way TS treats the array as immutable and takes the types of the values as they are, without generalizing. Then the types will be inferred correctly.

Comment: The compiler limitation affecting your update is probably a combination of the fact that [control flow analysis does not narrow generic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) and that conditional types are not easy to analyze for assignability.  There is [work being done](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27932) on the latter issue but I don't know if it will make it into the compiler anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript's [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) doesn't understand when different variables have correlated types.  If you narrow the type of one variable, it will not affect the type of another variable.  Additionally, it's difficult for TypeScript to perform type analysis on unresolved conditional types, so even if you changed your code to analyze the type of `seenObjects` intead of `obj`, you'd probably still get some type errors.

And you don't seem interested in adding additional runtime checks to convince the compiler that everything is safe.

Well: when in doubt and when you are smarter than the compiler, you can always use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to appease the compiler without changing the emitted JavaScript:

```
function stringify<T extends unknown>(
    obj: T,
    seenObjects: T extends Record<string, any> ? Set<Record<string, any>> : null
): string {
    if (isObject(obj)) {
        (seenObjects as Set<Record<string,any>>).add(obj); // type assertion 
    }    
    return 'The End';
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: *"TypeScript's control flow analysis doesn't understand when different variables have correlated types. "* -- But it does, the given example half works. When calling the function this information is indeed being used by TS. Unless you really very specifically mean "variable", i.e. excluding parameters *to* a function. But then you are just restating what can be observed here :-)

Comment: I mean [control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#control-flow-based-type-analysis) as opposed to generic type parameter inference. The half that doesn't work is type guarding `obj` to affect the type of `seenObjects` inside the function implementation. The half that does work is that in the function call sites, the compiler infers the type of `T` from the first param, which constrains the whole function signature. Generic type inference and control flow analysis have similar effects, I guess, but they are different compiler processes.